# Setting up environmental variables in Python

Tags: python, email, django-settings

Long time creeper, first time caller.
I was trying to create and use environ var to send gmail (smtp) from a settings.py file, but clearly I was doing it wrong because when I put in my password it worked, but when I used os.environ.get to hide the password.

I think I didn't call the environmental variable correctly but I have no clue! I got an authentication error

```py
import os

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxx----@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Thisworkedfine'
```

But when I used this it didn't work after defining 'EMAIL_USER' and 'EMAIL_PASS' in my System Properties.

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

Error from hell:

```py
SMTPSenderRefused at /password-reset/
(530, b'5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError c2sm2597974pjs.13 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')
```

HALP!

Comment: How are you setting the environment variables on the host? The settings file looks fine to me.

Comment: Your hypothesis is that reading the password form the environment does not work. What about testing your hypothesis by printing the content of `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`?

Comment: When I print `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` it doesn't seem to register the string I set for the password in the  `myEnvVal.py` file...which I just tried setting as described below, by creating the 'myEnvVal.py' file and importing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to set your variables in another python file and import the file.

Create a file say,`myEnvVal.py`

```
import os
# Set environment variables
def setVar():
    os.environ['EMAIL_USER'] = 'xxxx----@gmail.com'
    os.environ['EMAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'Thisworkedfine'
```

Now import this file

```
import os
import myEnvVal
myEnvVal.setVar()
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

Comment: Thanks pal!  Unfortunately, it still didn't work. No clue why.

Comment: @Natasha Go to [Allow less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and choose "Allow" to let less secure apps access your Google account and try again.

Comment: Yep, I did that.  I think its more about how I'm setting the variables.  TBH I'm sure I'm doing that wrong.

Comment: From the `myEnvVal.py` file `import os
#set environment variables

def setVar():
 os.environ['EMAIL_USER'] = "xxxx"
 os.environ['EMAIL_PASS'] = "Ohnothisannoysme1!"`

Comment: On printing those variable, are you getting the same values?
Also, check if there is a typo in the email or password.

Comment: Yes. When I `print('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')` I get `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`

Comment: Thank you all.  I had a typo in myEnvVar instead of myEnvVal.  MUCH APPRECIATED!

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend using dotenv module for python, I personally found this to be the most hassle free way to deal with environment variables.

Chuck all your evnironment variables in a .env file which is just key value pairs.
So the content of your .env file would look something like this:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxx----@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Thisworkedfine'
```

Then you in whichever python file you want to use your envars you can do this:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

EMAIL_BACKEND = os.getenv('EMAIL_BACKEND')
```

Then just make sure to include your .env in your .gitignore so that your secrets always stay local.

for more info check out the dotenv github repo [here](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv)

Comment: Thanks! Great idea.

Answer (score 0):

In another file (something like envvar.py) create two variables. One for email and one for password:

```
email = "me@something.com"
password = "somepassword"
```

then in your settings file:

```
import envvar

EMAIL_HOST_USER = envvar.email
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = envvar.password
```

Then add envvar to your gitignore